# Dynamic parameter doesn't work without CmdletBinding()

Tags: powershell

The parameter doesn't seem to be "set" as a parameter at all. Validate set doesn't work. Neither does autocomplete. Typing in the parameter name doesn't work either.

I know I did dynamic parameters before. But this time, I'm missing something. Just can't figure out what it is.

```
Function Add-Control() {
    DynamicParam {
        $ParamAttribute = New-Object Parameter
        $ParamAttribute.Mandatory = $true
        $ParamAttribute.ParameterSetName  = '__AllParameterSets'

        $AttributeCollection = New-Object System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[System.Attribute]

        $AttributeCollection.Add($ParamAttribute)

        $controlTypes = @("TextBox", "Label", "DataGrid")

        $AttributeCollection.Add((New-Object ValidateSet($controlTypes)))

        $RuntimeParam = New-Object System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameter('Type', [string], $AttributeCollection)

        $RuntimeParamDictionary = New-Object System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameterDictionary

        $RuntimeParamDictionary.Add('Type', $RuntimeParam)

        return $RuntimeParamDictionary
    }

    Process {
        Write-Host ($PSBoundParameters['Type'])
    }
}

Add-Control -Type "Test"
# $null
```

Comment: @briantist Should the solution be part of the question?

Comment: If the point is to make it more useful for others, then it should be more discoverable I think. I was going to comment that you might also want to be clearer about any error messages you received to better replicate what someone else might see if they made the same mistake (instead of just "it doesn't work"). In any case if you disagree you may roll back the edit.

Comment: I don't necessarily disagree. But I thought someone might overlook the question because they don't have "CmdletBinding" in their code, so they might think it doesn't apply to them. There are no errors in this case, btw (There certainly should be).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this is a stupid mistake, but I surely feel that way. I was missing

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param()
```

Both validate set and autocomplete work now.

Hopefully this helps others.

Comment: Clearly, a `DynamicParam` block should never be _quietly ignored_. Given that the problem still exists in PowerShell Core v6.0.1, I encourage you to [report the issue on GitHub](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues).

Comment: I filed an [issue report](https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/301869-powershell/suggestions/33558298-dynamic-param-is-silently-ignored) on UserVoice.

Comment: Thank you. UserVoice is for _Windows PowerShell_; so that it gets fixed in PowerShell _Core_, I've filed [a copy of your issue on GitHub](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6331).